# Como habilitar extensões do php dentro de um contêiner Docker

Tags: php, docker

preciso habilitar o curl porem estou usando o Docker para gerenciar minha aplicação.

Queria saber como eu poderia alterar informações do php.ini via terminal, eu tentei com gedit mas não tive sucesso.

Talvez uma solução pelo Dockerfile, mas sou leigo nesses tipo de configuração.

Qual a melhor forma de fazer essas configurações?

Comment: Como está seu Dockerfile?

Comment: Estou usando uma imagem do docker Hub, eboraas/Laravel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você utilizar a [imagem oficial do PHP](https://store.docker.com/images/php) para Docker, você pode instalar as extensões executando o comando `docker-php-ext-install`. Caso a extensão tenha algum pré-requisito, é preciso que ele seja instalado a partir do seu `Dockerfile` antes de executar `docker-php-ext-install`.

Veja um exemplo retirado da documentação da imagem:

```
FROM php:7.0-fpm
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng12-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/ \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

Sobre a extensão do `curl`, ela já vem habilitada por padrão na imagem oficial

```
root@58d96f139768:/# php -m
[PHP Modules]
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
fileinfo
filter
ftp
hash
iconv
```

Como a imagem que você está utilizando não é baseada na imagem oficial, sugiro que você pesquise por outra que te atenda e seja baseada na imagem oficial, pois assim fica mais fácil você fazer esse tipo de customizações.

Você pode se inspirar [nesse tutorial aqui](https://kyleferg.com/laravel-development-with-docker/) para criar os containers da sua aplicação.

Answer (score -1):

A melhor forma de fazer uma configuração em um container é gerando novamente uma imagem com a configuração correta. Você pode fazer isso criando um novo arquivo INI, que habilite sua extensão, enquanto no dockerfile você deve instalar essa extensão. Dependendo da extensão desejada, pode usar repositórios nativos da distribuição correspondente à imagem (a imagem base mais usada é a debian:jessie que usa APT como gerenciador de pacotes). Exemplo: [github.com/docker-gallery/wordpress-apache-php7](https://github.com/docker-gallery/wordpress-apache-php7)

Mas atendendo ao teu cenário em que você já tem um container rodando, use `docker exec -it [nomeDoContainer|idDoContainer] /bin/bash` e terá acesso ao terminal dentro do container. Use o terminal para fazer o setup do seu container.

> Mas lembre-se, esses arquivos morrerão com seu container. É mais sadio fazer isso antes no dockerfile e recriar seu container.